# C#: How can I download the file from the GoogleDocs?

Tags: c#, .net, download

Windows 7, .Net 4.5.1. My computer is in the domain. I try to download the dll-file from the GoogleDocs:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("userName", "password");
client.DownloadFile("https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7H_2Cq9tBXdWkU0andsR1dWM0U/view?usp=sharing",
  fileName);
```

But I get an exception with the message:

> The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication
>   Required.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the google drive api for this https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-cs

Comment: Is it impossible to download the shared file through its link without the google drive api?